# Trying to recreate JSON format (already parsed)

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I want to recreate this exact format:

```
activities =     (
                {
            "activity_begindate" = "";
            "activity_category_id" = 1;
            "activity_city" = " ";
            "activity_description" = "";
            "activity_email" = "";
            "activity_enddate" = "2013-10-15";
            "activity_id" = 121;
            "activity_image" = "";
            "activity_time" = "15:46";
            "activity_title" = "";
            "activity_where" = "anywhere ";
            "bitly_url" = "";
            gotooffer = "";
            latitude = "";
            longitude = "";
            "user_fullname" = "";
            "user_id" = ;
        },
```

Where exactly would I start with this one? Does this require I create an NSDictionary with different keys?

Comment: Okay, cool. Hey, thanks for RSS Reader btw!

Comment: You're welcome. One question: were you really looking for creating a **data structure,** or did you want to **serialize this structure to JSON?** I couldn't deduce that from the question.

Comment: It was what Joel pointed out. I think I need to learn how to read these formats a little better, but i think I can figure this one out now. Thank you, though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be an `NSDictionary` with one key `activities` which contains an `NSArray` of `NSDictionaries`.

Comment: Okay, sweet. I thought so, but thank for pointing me in the right direction.